# Expecting member declaration (this happens when using a variable from another class)

Tags: kotlin

**The code here works:**

```kotlin
fun main(){
    val pizza = random()
    print(pizza.num)
}

class random{
    val num = 5
}
```

**But the code here does not work**

```kotlin
fun main(){
    val pizza = random()
    print(pizza.num)
}

class random{
    val num = 5
    num = 7
}
```

The only difference is that in the last line of code I reassign the variable num. The only thing I did was change this variable from 5 to 7.

Why is this causing errors?

**Note** This is the online IDE I was using: https://developer.android.com/training/kotlinplayground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

Firstly, you can't reassign `val`s. you need to change that to `var`

Secondly, you can't do assignments directly in a class body, only declarations.
However, you could put it in an `init` block like this to get the desired result:

```
class random{
    var num = 5
    init {
        num = 7
    }
}
```

you might want to read the documentation about kotlin classes [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html)